# Android studio issue with PNG

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, libpng, aapt

I migrated a project from eclipse to Android Studio. When I try to run the app, the build crashes with the following:

```
AAPT err(102196253): I:\Workspace\AudioRecStudio\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\AudioRecStudio\audiorecresources\unspecified\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_playback.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(892575140): I:\Workspace\AudioRecStudio\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\AudioRecStudio\audiorecresources\unspecified\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\ic_pause_notification.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(1822584146): I:\Workspace\AudioRecStudio\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\AudioRecStudio\audiorecresources\unspecified\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\ic_settings_nav_drawer.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
 ....... and so on....
```

I must mention I cannot run the project. I didn't find any solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow your system is promoting the warnings to errors.  Applications can force the sRGB-checking to be skipped by putting the following line in your application and recompiling it

```
png_set_option(png_ptr, PNG_SKIP_sRGB_CHECK_PROFILE, PNG_OPTION_ON);
```

as explained in the libpng manual.  This checking was added at libpng version 1.6.0 and the option to skip checking was added at libpng version 1.6.11.

The real fix is to repair the PNG files, if you have access to them, by deleting the bad sRGB profile, or to request that they be repaired upstream if you don't. If you haven't upgraded libpng to the current version, libpng-1.6.17, try that, because some profiles are accepted by libpng-1.6.12 and later that were erroneously rejected by libpng-1.6.0 through 1.6.11.  Also, try to find out if there is a way to configure your application so it handles warnings as warnings and not as fatal errors.

As a last resort you could downgrade your libpng to version 1.5.x (the latest version in the 1.5 series is 1.5.22) which doesn't check sRGB profiles, or you could rebuild libpng16 with PNG_sRGB_PROFILE_CHECKS=-1 defined.

Comment: Thanks, but where I can add this line? I'm not so used with Android Studio build files system

Comment: It goes in the source code for the application.  If you don't have access to that, you could downgrade your libpng to version 1.5.x, or your could rebuild libpng16 with PNG_sRGB_PROFILE_CHECKS=-1 defined.

Comment: I want to avoid doing hacking stuff, I want to work.clean. Android studio brings only problems and I am tempted to switch back to Eclipse

Comment: I installed ImageMagick lib and used it to repair the PNG files. Running:"find . -type f -name "*.png" -exec convert {} -strip {} \;" in the folder containing the png files did the job.

Comment: can anybody tell me where should i put this?  png_set_option(png_ptr, PNG_SKIP_sRGB_CHECK_PROFILE, PNG_OPTION_ON);

Comment: The png_set_option() goes in your "C" source, immediately after you have created the png_ptr (read_ptr or whatever you might be calling it)